# Parse.com how to connect an object to a user?

Tags: android, reference, parse-platform

When trying to add a reference from my own object to a Parse user, I got the error

> "Cannot save a ParseUser that is not authenticated."

```
ParseUser usr = [query some user];
ParseObject obj = new MyParseObjectReferencingAUser();
obj.put("the_user", usr);
obj.save();
```

I did not touch the ParseUser, nor did I try to save it. But for some reason Parse tries to save it together with my object - which of course fails because I am not logged in as that user, so I cannot modify it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to link to a user (or probably any other read-only object) you need to use an object without data [createWithoutData(String className, String objectId)](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#createWithoutData%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
ParseUser usr = [query some user];
ParseObject obj = new MyParseObjectReferencingAUser();
ParseObject usrNoData = ParseUser.createWithoutData(usr.getClassName(), usr.getObjectId());
obj.put("the_user", usrNoData);
obj.save();
```

It is recommended to use Parse's function object.getClassName(), and not explicitly guess the class name, because the Parse object's name can be different than what you would expect. For instance in this case the class name for ParseUser is "_User" and not "ParseUser".